# Why is INotifyPropertyChanged crashing my app? How to properly implement the update functionality of x:Bind?

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I have an app where I want to change the opacity of an image when it is selected in a GridView. I created a One-Way binding in the page XAML using x:Bind, but when I selected something it didn't change the opacity. I am not sure if I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged  correctly - when I run in debugging (VS2022) the application crashes without any exception messages.

From what I can tell, the app crashes upon assignment of opacity, as it crashes when the object is constructed. Everything in my app worked prior to implementing INotifyPropertyChanged (I referenced [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-8.0)).

Here is my relevant code...

User control XAML:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="myProject.Classes.Controls.IUAreaExpander"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="using:myProject.Classes.Controls"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Control.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemHighlightColor">Cyan</SolidColorBrush>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Control.Resources>

    <controls:AdaptiveGridView
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind filteredImages, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectionChanged="Items_Select">
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:WorkingImage">
                <Grid>
                    <Image
                        Opacity="{x:Bind opacity, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Source="{x:Bind bmpSource, Mode=OneWay}">
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
        <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ItemHighlightColor}" />
            </Style>
        </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
```

User Control code-behind:

```html
namespace myProject.Classes.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class IUAreaExpander : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<WorkingImage> allImages;

        public IUAreaExpander()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            allImages = new ObservableCollection<WorkingImage>();
        }

        private void Items_Select(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (WorkingImage a in e.AddedItems) {
                a.Select();
            }
            foreach (WorkingImage r in e.RemovedItems) {
                r.Deselect();
            }
            Bindings.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

WorkingImage class:

```html
namespace myProject.Classes
{
    public class WorkingImage : WorkingFile, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        public double opacity
        {  
            get  
            {  
                return this.opacity;  
            }
            set  
            {  
                if (value != this.opacity)  
                {
                    this.opacity = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public BitmapSource bmpSource;

        public WorkingImage(StorageFile inFile) : base(inFile)
        {
            base.file = inFile;
            opacity = 1;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void Select()
        {
            opacity = 0.5;
        }

        public void Deselect()
        {
            opacity = 1;
        }
        #endregion

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `opacity` seems to cause a `StackOverFlowException` because you don't use a backing field, but the property itself to assign the value to. Thus running into an endless reentrance cycle.

Before implementing INPC you seem to have directly bound to the field `opacity`, and had no property of that name. So the issue arose only with adding that property, but not backing its value.

Changing it to something like this, might fix it:

```
public class WorkingImage : WorkingFile, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private double opacity;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        
        public double Opacity
        {  
            get  
            {  
                return this.opacity;  
            }
            set  
            {  
                if (value != this.opacity)  
                {
                    this.opacity = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        public BitmapSource bmpSource;

        public WorkingImage(StorageFile inFile) : base(inFile)
        {
            base.file = inFile;
            Opacity = 1;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void Select()
        {
            Opacity = 0.5;
        }

        public void Deselect()
        {
            Opacity = 1;
        }
        #endregion

    } 
}
```

And in the xaml also use the Upper case `Opacity` then...

```
<Image
                        x:Name="SomeImage"
                        Width="200"
                        Height="200"
                        Opacity="{x:Bind Opacity, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Source="{x:Bind bmpSource, Mode=OneWay}">
                    </Image>
```

Comment: Thanks lidqy, this worked! Out of curiosity, how did you identify the StackOverflowException? I didn't get any messages in Visual Studio, wondering if you had another way to find that out.

Comment: @MarkL It has to be an StackOverflowException because the property setter of opacity in this line `if (value != this.opacity)` calls the getter and the getter keeps on calling itself, which leads to a stack overflow.